# Can a recurrent neural network learn slightly different sequences at once?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

Can a recurrent neural network be used to learn a sequence with slightly different variations? For example, could I get an RNN trained so that it could produce a sequence of consecutive integers or alternate integers if I have enough training data?

For example, if I train using

```
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,5
3,4,5,6
```

and so on
and also train the same network using

```
1,3,5,7
2,4,6,8
3,5,7,9
```

and so on,
would I be able to predict both sequences successfully for the test set?

What if I have even more variations in the training data like sequences of every three integers or every four integers, et cetera?

Comment: Your **brain** is an RNN, and it learns *many many many* sequences at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, provided there is enough information in the sequence so that it is not ambiguous, a neural network should be able to learn to complete these sequences correctly.

You should note a few details though:

- Neural networks, and ML models in general, are bad at *extrapolation*. A simple network is very unlikely to learn about sequences in general. It will never learn the concept of sequence logic in the way a child quickly would. So if you feed in test data outside of its experience (e.g. steps of 3 between items, when they were not in the training data), it will perform badly.
- Neural networks prefer scaled inputs - a common pre-processing step is to normalise to mean 0 standard deviation 1 for each input column. Whilst it is possible for a network to accept larger range of numbers at inputs, that will reduce effectiveness of training. With a generated training set such as artificial numeric sequences, you may be able to force your way through that by training for longer with more examples.
- You will need more neurons, and more layers, to support a larger variation of sequences.
- For a RNN, it will predict badly if the sequence it has processed so far is ambiguous. E.g. if you train 1,2,3,4 and 1,2,3,5 with equal numbers of samples, it will predict either 4.5 (for regression) or 50% chance 4 or 5 (for classifier) when it shown sequence 1,2,3 and asked to predict.

Comment: Could you possibly explain the intuition of an RNN learning two or more different sequences?

Comment: @Sibi: I don't fully understand your comment. What form would an intuition take? If you want something detailed, then might be best to write a different question. But essentially a RNN can learn arbitrary sequences. The fact that your examples are mathematically related is of no real consequence. The network will learn 1,2,3,(4) separately from 2,3,4,(5), it doesn't "understand" what is going on.